# Application on SAP Cloud Foundry - OAuth 2.0 - Error: Something went amiss

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

I have been delevopping and deploying a python application for the SAP Cloud Foundry and trying to implement an authentication check using OAuth2.0.

Using this [Tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/btp-cf-buildpacks-python-create.html).
[Link to Code](https://github.com/nickx0815/SAP_CF_PYTHON) Note: I excluded the `node_modules/@sap/approuter` for storage reasons

When I open `https://cproPythonAI_web.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com` the login site is loaded correctly, but after the login I get to a Error-Site.

[image: Error Site with message]

Kind regards and thanks for help
Nick

- did every step of the tutorial
- entered "authenticationMethod": "none" to the xs-app.json. Then i get redirect to the index.html, but of course the authentification is skipped

Comment: `I excluded the node_modules/@sap/approuter for storage reasons` I believe it will not work without approuter module. What exact problem ahve you solved by removing it?

Comment: No what i meant is, that i excluded it from my git repo

Comment: that what I meant too, it will not work without the approuter entry in the `package.json` and without the code in `node_modules` folder. Learn more here https://blogs.sap.com/2020/04/03/sap-application-router/

Comment: Locally node_modules is there, i just excluded it from the git, cuz it would be way to big, storage reasons